# Magento 2 dynamic UI form

Tags: magento, magento2, uicomponents

Based on the type(value) I want to render the different fields in the same form. And also I want to make some field as readonly or disabled based on the value.

Refer the below screenshot for more understanding.

This form is based on **type 1**
[image]

This form is based on **type 2**
[image]

**Type is a hidden field**

This I can achieve by Widget Generic form but I want to implement in UI form, Because in my form I am also using magento default address form(UI).

Please help me if anybody knows.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Magento documentation?

Comment: Yes. I tried, but I'm not getting any solution.
I referred this link [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-form.html)

Comment: You don't seem to have a problem with any code at the moment. You seem to want us to code for you. You really need to have a go and then come here with any code that you can't get working. Have you read [ask]?

Comment: @alex: try to use switcherConfig.